# I wanto to build an array with values read from a file... how can i do that?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a file to read, then extract some values from this file and re-assign these values to write a readable ascii file. The point is that I cannot find a way to write the values in a proper way.

The file I am using is an ascii file produced by tecplot. At the end, I would like to produce the file with some header and variable description.

I tried different strategies until now, but I produce only single arrays with two values and not a "proper" matrix. Moreover, I don't manage to write each element as I would like to, I mean keep in memory the elements assigned step by step in the loop.

Here's the code:

```
f=open('profile_1D.dat', 'r')
data = []
outfile = open('outfile.dat','w+')

for line in f:
  line = line.split()
  data.append(line)       

data=np.array(data)
arg=(data[43:])

newarr=np.zeros((len(arg),2))
for lists in arg:
  newarray=np.array((lists[2],lists[34]))
  newarray.astype(float)

print newarray
print newarray.shape
```

`

Like that I obviously get only the last line of the "array".

`['6.17926421404682' '1.59400321081525E-11']`

and its shape is `(2,)`.
I would like to have a (300,2) array filled like that:

```
['5.53645484949833' '1.86479953164333E-11']
['5.55719063545151' '1.8377081954255E-11']
['5.57792642140468' '1.81061685920767E-11']
['5.59866220735786' '1.78352552298984E-11']
```

Comment: Where is newarr=np.zeros((len(arg),2) used?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo mistake in the code averything is newarr, so consistent.                                                        newarr=np.zeros((len(arg),2))
newarr = list(newarr)

#
#
for lists in arg:
    newarr.append((lists[2],lists[34]))

Answer (score 0):

I think you get the last line because you don't append the `newarray`.

Try :

```
for lists in arg:
    newarray.append(np.array((lists[2],lists[34])))
```

Comment: Mmmm so now converting the array to a list it seems to work, but the first thing I get is:array([0., 0.]), array([0., 0.]), array([0., 0.]), array([0., 0.]), array([0., 0.]), array([0., 0.]), array([0., 0.]), array([0., 0.]), array([0., 0.]), array([0., 0.]), array([0., 0.]), array([0., 0.]), array([0., 0.]), array([0., 0.]), array([0., 0.]), array([0., 0.]), array([0., 0.]), array([0., 0.]), array([0., 0.]), array([0., 0.]), array([0., 0.]), array([0., 0.]), array([0., 0.]),  and then it start with the sequence. Moreover I would like to have the output to be good to be written on a file

Comment: I mean, formatting the result in two columns with the right lenght.

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem.So the point was that creating an array of zeros included the array of zeros itself and then appended the other elements which were elements of a list, so it is like it "merged" the things together. Like that is much more easy because I directly create an empty list and then fill the list itself with the values I wanted. Here the solution:  'code' :  arg=data[43:]
newarr = list()

#
#
for lists in arg:
    newarr.append((lists[2],lists[34]))


newarr=np.array(newarr)

Comment: Now the question is: how do I write this on a file?